# How to use Git for phpBB deployment on VPS

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment, phpbb, phpbb3

I was quite surprised that I couldn't find step-by-step instructions for phpBB git deployment to production environments.

So there are some [articles](https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/dev/3.1.x/development/git.html) that show how to set up a local branch for local development but still not a word about deployment to production servers.

What I've been thinking of:

**Development**

1. Clone a repository: `git clone git@github.com:phpbb/phpbb.git`
2. Remove the origin remote: `git remote remove origin`
3. Add my own origin: `git remote add origin ...`
4. Add an upstream remote: `git remote add upstream git@github.com:phpbb/phpbb.git`
5. Checkout the 3.3.x code: `git checkout upstream/3.3.x`
6. Update `.gitignore` to include my changes (extensions/templates/language files) (?)
7. Make some changes
8. Get the recent upstream updates: `git pull upstream 3.3.x`
9. Commit the changes
10. Push the changes

**Production**

1. Set up a bare repository on a production server
2. Set up a post-receive hook that will move the "phpBB" folder to my webserver's "www" folder overwriting the existing folders
3. Execute some scripts (?)

Please share how do you deploy the phpBB code to live production servers.